# Cannot use alert() in a jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

When using jQuery to make an AJAX call, for the time being I want to just want to have a popup box (using `alert()`) showing me the response text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jeobutton").mouseup(function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        $.ajax({ url: 'getdata.php',
            data: // <parameters>
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output) {
                // do something
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert("<some error>");
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The response text prints out fine. However, the `alert()` dialog is nowhere to be found.

Please help this poor noob.

Comment: What does `console.log(alert.toString())` show?

Comment: `function alert() { [native code] }`

Comment: I put your code into  jsfiddle, and it worked. I did delete the "data:" line, as it is missing a comma as is.

Comment: Can I have a link to said fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle with something very close to your code, working, the alert box pops up.

http://jsfiddle.net/pN869/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jeobutton").mouseup(function() {
        console.log("clicked");
        var $button = $(this);
        $.ajax({ url: 'getdata.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(output) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert("<some error>");
                console.error(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your solution does indeed work in JSFiddle, but I still don't get a dialog on my local server.

Comment: Very odd. What version of jQuery are you using locally? And what browser?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 through Google's CDN at this link: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js` and Google Chrome on elementary OS Luna.

Comment: Any errors at all in your console? A syntax error somewhere else could cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: The only error in the JS console is the one I logged through `console.error()`.

Comment: Your browser, is it Midori, or really Chrome?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to try window.alert(), or maybe try window.confirm()?

Comment: Neither of those functions work. However, Midori displays the dialog correctly. I'm using Chrome version `30.0.1599.47 (Official Build 223717) beta` and JavaScript version `V8 3.20.17.7`. I'm going to try to get the latest stable version (29, I think?)

Answer (score -1):

Clean the browser cache. There will likely be branded the option of not showing more alert.
Testing in different browsers.

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: I guess that @thatJavaNerd he has cleared his browser cache during the last year. Plz look at the question's date!